# Change keyboard layout (English UK) on command line to English US

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. The keyboard layout is English US everywhere except for the Command Line where it works in English UK. Terminal also has English US. How do I change the default keyboard layout in Command Line to English US?

Also, I think it might be worth noting here, that when I had installed Ubuntu (dual boot with Windows 8. 1), I had initially set the language as English UK, but later changed it to English US from the system settings.

Comment: What exactly is the "Command Line" as opposed to the terminal? Do you mean a virtual console (tty)?

Comment: CTRL + ALT + F2 brings up the Command Line

Comment: lang=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @terdon I think you second guessed yourself, Ctrl+Alt+F2 should indeed be a virtual terminal (the 'Run Dialog' is plain Alt+F2). I'm not sure if `console-setup` is installed by default, but perhaps the OP should try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`?

Comment: @steeldriver you are absolutely correct, I did not notice the Ctrl! Thanks, that makes this answerable!

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks a lot! Your method worked for me.

Comment: @user241411 really? You ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`? That only gave me options to change encoding and font, not the keyboard layout. I had to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data` to get the layout.

Comment: Yes, I had to run both... Thanks to you too. :)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Update 2017-04-13**: This seems to have changed in recent Ubuntu versions and running `sudo apt-get install console-common` will try to remove other packages. So, for recent Ubuntu versions, use this instead *(Tested in 17.04)*:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

---

The simplest way would indeed be as @steeldriver [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434849/change-keyboard-layout-english-uk-on-command-line-to-english-us?noredirect=1#comment566503_434849) to open a terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install console-common
```

That will install the `console-common` package and in the process allow you to chose your console layout. If that is already installed, use this to bring up the same wizard and set the layout:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

Tested on 13.10, and taken from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1758915).

Comment: Using Ubutnu 14.04 I was able to set the keyboard on a text-console. But after a reboot it would be reset to the previous settings. Only after issuing a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`I was able to set it permanently.

Comment: Seems like a bit of kludge to do something so seemingly simple - but hey, it worked on a Raspberry PI (running raspbian), so cool, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with 16.04. Installing `console-common` wants to remove packages cryptsetup, plymouth, lightdm, and some others. `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` does work however.

Comment: Goddamn it. After I ran this command and reboot, it stuck at the purple blank screen. Turns out this command also removed plymouth and unity. @OlafDietsche is right!

Comment: > sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
This worked for me.

Comment: If I have a custom kmap file how do I make it show up in this list? Or a custom xkb symbols file?

Answer (score 80):

The above didn't work for me, but this did. From terminal enter the following command:

```
setxkbmap us
```

Comment: This worked for me when using Chrome Remote Desktop to Mint even though the keyword layout is  correct when logged in normally.

Comment: 2018 - working on Ubuntu 11.x

Comment: and me wanting to go the other way (mint) setxkbmap gb

Comment: setxkbmap working on arch (loadkeys not)

Comment: Works on LUbuntu 20_04

Comment: Works not permanently

Comment: Note for UK keyboard use 'gb'

Comment: Works on Bunsenlabs Beryllium (Debian Bullseye). Exactly what I needed, method to quickly _and temporarily_ change the layout on X applications

Comment: This made my keyboard layout stuck on something and it conflicted with ui. Ubuntu 22 Gnome

Answer (score 74):

Run this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I needed to reboot so that it takes effect, could you mention it in the answer? Cheers

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger I didn't have to reboot to get that into effect.

Comment: No reboot is required.

Comment: Yes, running 16.04 (Thinkpad T430) and sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration worked a treat for me. Did not have to reboot just chose Generic 105 Int Keyboard and UK layout to recover my Keyboard after it had mysteriously change to US layout... Thanks

Comment: I had to logout and back in to have it taking effect. [i3wm]

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04 server in freshly installed KVM machine. Applied UK layout, still have US layout.

Comment: It did require a reboot for be (Debian 11), so I guess if it doesn't work do try rebooting, even though it appears to work without a reboot for some.

Answer (score 44):

I have a console only (without X) Linux running inside a VirtualBox. Needed to change layout from US keyboard to a German one. I used [loadkeys](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/loadkeys.1.html) (*load keyboard translation tables* by [kbd](https://kbd-project.org/) package):

```
loadkeys de
```

To make it permanent use systemd's localectl:

```
localectl set-keymap de
```

From [manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/localectl.1.html):

> **set-keymap MAP [TOGGLEMAP]**
> Set the system keyboard mapping for the console and X11. This takes a mapping name
> (such as "de" or "us"), and possibly a second one to define a toggle keyboard mapping.
> Unless --no-convert is passed, the selected setting is also applied as the default
> system keyboard mapping of X11, after converting it to the closest matching X11
> keyboard mapping. Use list-keymaps for a list of available keyboard mappings (see
> below).

### See also

- Arch wiki: [Linux console/Keyboard configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration)

Comment: Thanks to you I found the solution for me, running my server in VNC. Your command changes it temporarily. To make it permanent I used `localectl set-keymap de`.

Comment: Thanks. This works on a fresh server 16.04 install out of the box. The above setxkbmap solution requires to install some X11 utils, which IMHO did not seem the right thing to do on a server.

Comment: For Spanish use: `loadkeys es`

Comment: @Alex, Command not found

Comment: I am on LUbuntu 20?04. Does not work, do I have to reload the terminal or restart pc

Comment: for american-english (which is presumably the qwerty) `sudo loadkeys us` , os : ubuntu 10.04LTS

Comment: That should be the accepted answer 

Answer (score 9):

I'm running 14.04 LTS with a standard US keyboard.  My problem was that I had relied on the installer to choose US-Intl for me and it caused "dead keys" and improper formation of the " and ' keys (as well as others I don't know about, I'm sure).

After a lot of frustration and trial and error, I ran the "`sudo apt-get install console-common`" suggestion and it fixed my problem, but only while I was logged in.

When I logged out, restarted the server and back in, it failed.

It only took hold permanently when I executed the "`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`" command and specified the generic US keyboard.

"`setxkbmap`" did not work for me.

It seems that (I don't KNOW) **setxkbmap is obsolete in 14.04 LTS**.

Comment: `setxkbmap gb` worked for me just now in 16.04.01 LTS

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu/Debian you have `/etc/default/keyboard` config file which actually manages the keyboard layout on your distro. When you boot your system the `/etc/default/keyboard` file is read by setup scripts along with other config files. If you look  at the output of  `/etc/default/keyboard`  file you can see my keybord layout is set to german `de` :

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

It is not good idea (like other config files) to directly change the attributes of `/etc/default/keyboard` file.

To change the layout or model of your keyboard always use following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

**Additional Information.**

You should probably also change your locale!

Use `locale -a` to show all possible languages:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_AT.utf8
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
...
POSIX
```

If your locale is not in the above list, then you have to generate it:

```
$ sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8
Generating locales...
  fr_FR.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

The default settings are stored in `/etc/default/locale`:

You can either manually configure it, or use the tool:

```
update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

[More details](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Locales_unter_Ubuntu_konfigurieren) (german source).

Comment: This does not answer the OP. Locale and keyboard are quite unrelated.