# No polish signs in terminal

Tags: command-line, encoding

I have changed my `.bashrc` file, so that `$LANG` variable is always set to
`en_US` when I run new shell. This is because I have a program for making plots which takes the sign as a decimal separator based on the language.

When `$LANG` is set to `pl_PL` then I have a comma, instead of a point.

It was all fine, but after I made automatic update to my system, it turned out that I cannot type in polish signs into terminal.

For instance this is unicode for "ó" letter: U+00D3
but I see "C3" when I type "ó' into the terminal.

Now, when I switch to another account, the problem is gone.

I checked content of

```
/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
```

It says:

```
pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

I also run

```
dpkg-reconfigure locale
```

It doesn't do any good.

What can I do if I don't want to switch to another account?

Comment: Have you tried tweaking settings in Settings > Keyboard > Text Entry? Do you have that little "PL" icon on your dash?

Comment: Well, I can't find it anywhere in Settings, but I can see that my keyboard is still set to polish. For instance, I can use polish signs in mozilla.

Comment: Weird....  Take a look at that maybe it'll help you, it seems to describe same problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/434849/change-keyboard-layout-english-uk-on-command-line-to-english-us

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I have managed to solve the problem.
I have hashed out `export LANG=en_US` in `.bashrc` file. And now I use

> export LC_NUMERIC=C

to get point as a decimal separator. After I restarted system I got my polish signs back.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in debian. Look at: 
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=818065#85
You have to do:

```
rm /etc/console-setup/cached_*
```

These files can be recreated by

```
setupcon --save-only
```

This wiil do the change in:

```
/etc/console-setup/cached_setup_keyboard.sh
-loadkeys '/tmp/tmpkbd.iDWdSi' > '/dev/null'
+loadkeys '/etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz' > '/dev/null'.
```

Yep they did not fix this yet.