# Changing keyboard language doesn't work kubuntu 17.10

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, language-support

I need to change the language from keyboard for example : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or similar.

I have already installed all language.

Switching keyboard language by <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> does not work. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't change language. I
can't type my language even with ru, bg, en input switched on in language bar.

The language is bar missing.

**Edit from comments:**

I have UK and Bulgarian keyboards enabled, I have enabled <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as the primary short cut and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> as the alternate in my settings. the current selected keyboard layout is not indicated in the systray and I cannot find a plasmoid for it either. If I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> nothing happens. If I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>At</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> a rounded grey square with icon of a globe and letters UK (representing UK layout) are displayed on screen, if I hit the combination again, it again shows uk and does not switch the layout.

Comment: ? Super ? what's that Super key ????

Comment: Super+Space  not working .All key combinations for changes language not working. How to Make set shortcuts to change keyboard layout?  THANKS.

Comment: i know that from the beginning when i install first day kubuntu 17.10. i have all actualization. i set restore points . also the same problem.

Comment: I have UK and Bulgarian keyboards enabled, I have enabled Alt+Shift as primary short cut and Ctrl+Alt+K as alternative in my setting. Current selected keyboard layout is not indicated in the systray and i can not find a plasmoid for it either. If I hit Alt+Shift nothing happens. If I hit Ctrl+At+K a rounded grey square with icon of a globe and letters UK (representing UK layout) are displayed on screen, if I hit the combination again, it again shows uk and does not switch the layout.

Comment: Yes i have installed the Bulgarian language support in addition to the keyboard layout. But i can't type in different language, only  English . All menu design it's on Bulgarian language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are talking of Ubuntu desktop or server but this is how I walked passed both situations with Ubuntu 17.10.

For Ubuntu desktop, → *settings* → *region and language* after selecting your languages, make sure u click on *manage installed language* to make sure they are  available for support. I combine "windows logo" key + "space" key to switch between languages.

[image]

And for Ubuntu server, you can use this command [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434849/change-keyboard-layout-english-uk-on-command-line-to-english-us) (a similar response to your question). Following @steeldriver 's cmd approach, it worked for me, so I guess you will find something like *pc / qwerty / Bulgarian / standard / standard* amongst other layouts in your language(s). Hope it helps.

Comment: Here's an inline link to [Google Photos](https://photos.app.goo.gl/eDR67T8jgc2HfCn23).

Comment: There is a solution to the problem. I reinstalled Kubuntu. I installed the Bulgarian language and everything worked.