# Croatian layout missing letters x y q w (CUI only solution required)

Tags: keyboard, console, mint, layout

I have dual boot with Linux Mint 17.1. (based on Ubuntu 14.04.) and after installing python 2.7.9 I get BLACK SCREEN  after login. I can then open CONSOLE (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>) which requires me to login again and I can. But my keyboard layout is messed up; all keys except <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>z</kbd> correspond to Croatian layout. The keys mentioned produce only ♦ (black diamond character). As you can imagine I can't type in commands that include words like keYboard, laYout,  X11...

What I CAN do is edit `/etc/default/keyboard` or similar files as nano allows me to save files using god-given <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>.

Current values:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105" 
XKBLAYOUT="hr" 
XKBVARIANT="unicodeus" 
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

I'd very much like to avoid changing layout to US or similar because I'm afraid I will no longer be able to type in my own password upon next boot.

I've done update and upgrade and upgrade-distro, I would like to just be able to test `startx` command but this fricking layout mess won't let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install console-common
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

Select layout from full list as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434849/change-keyboard-layout-english-uk-on-command-line-to-english-us).