# Ubuntu 16.04 not booting properly after trying to change the keyboard settings

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with dual boot along with Windows 10 on Lenovo Legion Y520. I was programming on Ubuntu and the `"` `'` symbols were not being displayed correctly while trying to code. To solve this problem I tried to follow the solutions given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434849/change-keyboard-layout-english-uk-on-command-line-to-english-us).

First I tried the command:

```
sudo apt-get install console-common
```

I selected some options that seemed similar to the qwerty US english layout (I am sorry I don't exactly remember the options I chose).
After applying the changes, I tried using the `"` `'` symbols again, but again they were not being displayed correctly. I tried another solution given in the link mentioned above:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

After again selecting some options, I had to reboot the system for the changes to apply. Upon rebooting, instead of the conventional 16.04 login screen, I get this grey login screen:

[image: Login screen]

I tried clicking on my username shown in the blue box and fill my password but the system won't log me in. I tried rebooting several times but, no success. Can some one help me out with how to get my Ubuntu functioning back normally?

Comment: Try to open a tty console with `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, log in from there, and let us know what the command `cat /etc/default/keyboard` outputs.

Comment: That looks like a log-in screen albeit with a plain black background instead of the default wallpaper. What *exactly* happens when you try to log in? Is there any error message? What *exactly* do you mean `"` and `'` "were not being displayed correctly"? Did the font glyphs look weird or did the key strokes result in altogether different characters? (Which ones?) In what context does the issue occur (Grub, virtual console, graphical session, virtual terminal, specific application(s)…)?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson here is the output that I get: https://imgur.com/a/IZaetC2

Comment: @DavidFoerster when I try to login, rather than being taken to the default desktop screen, I again get the login screen and there are no error messages. What I mean by " and ' not being displayed correctly is that the font glyph looked weird (they had a much smaller display size, almost like a dot). But the problem occurred with only these 2 symbols whenever I code or write something in a text editor/word/powerpoint/command-line. As a result when ever I would try to run a code, I would run into syntax errors.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? See [How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?](/q/440087/175814) for how to do that in your situation. Thanks.

Comment: The font glyph problem is entirely unrelated from the log-in problem. Could you please open a separate question for it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: `/etc/default/keyboard` looks ok, and I don't think your changing of keyboard layout is related to the login issue.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: While what you say about program output is generally good advice, I'm not sure of how to accomplish that from a tty console.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: See [the accepted answer](/a/440088/175814) to the question linked in my previous comment, aptly titled “How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?”.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Good point. (I thought something similar after having posted my comment...)