# Enable dead key usage in urxvt

Tags: keyboard, dead-keys, rxvt

I'm able to normaly use dead keys over the whole system.

FYI I live in Brazil and we use accented letters, as in é á ó ã õ.

We need dead key support for this as we type first the accent key " ´ " and then the proper key " a " to get and á

It doesn't work in terminals like 'st' and 'urxvt' tough. I've searched thoroughly over the internet to no avail.

EDIT:

[Change keyboard layout (English UK) on command line to English US](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434849/change-keyboard-layout-english-uk-on-command-line-to-english-us) doesn't solve my problem, as it is urxvt and st related.

Modern terminals like "tilix" or "gnome-terminal" are able to produce "á é é" characters

Comment: Change keyboard layout for the console as indicated in the duplicate question (sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration)

Comment: Unfortunately not, tried both 'console-setup' and 'console-data'. Last one had a portuguese standard which looks right but returns error: Looking for keymap to install:                         
br-abnt2
adding map 3 violates explicit keymaps line
Failed to load keymap!

Answer (score 1):

I have the English US keyboard, and I switch to the English US International keyboard with dead keys to type accents in Spanish. I have no issue typing accents in urxvt. I am using Debian 11.

To set my keyboard, I can use the commands:

```
setxkbmap us
setxkbmap us intl
```

Furthermore, I have a keybinding set to run this script to toggle between keyboard layouts:

```
#!/bin/bash

setxkbmap -query | grep -q "variant" &&
(setxkbmap us && notify-send -t 400 "Keyboard US") ||
(setxkbmap us intl && notify-send -t 400 "Keyboard US International")
```