# Disk decryption on boot not working on Lubuntu

Tags: boot, 22.04, lubuntu, encryption

There's a prompt on boot. After entering my password and hitting enter nothing happens and boot doesn't continue. It just freezes. I'm on 22.04.3.

Comment: How did you get to this state? What, precisely and completely, step-by-step description needed. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: It's a fresh install.

Comment: What language are you using?  When you enter your password during the installer process, the machine will know about your local language configuration as the desktop itself was operating (in *live* mode) where as at unlock there is no internet or localization EXCEPT as provided by your machine firmware (*which may differ to your actual location/language*)..   If you used keys that differ due to language, you should use keys that are identical to avoid https://bugs.launchpad.net/calamares/+bug/1827501

Comment: The *freezes* though implies to me something else, a language issue with the keyboard config will not cause a freeze...  What do you specifically mean by freeze?  Can you switch to a text terminal & try and login there?  Can you direct the kernel using SySrq commands  (ie. have you a frozen kernel due to panic?)  or is only the GUI frozen (ie. non-GUI features such as switching to text terminal, or bypassing all GUI & using SysRq commands direct to kernel will function)

Comment: Press <kbd>e</kbd> in GRUB to edit the kernel command line, and remove `quiet splash`. Then press the key to continue boot and post the messages that appear after entering your password.

Comment: @DanielT Alternatively, press `Esc` during boot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar but not quite the same issue. I'm posting this since it may be useful to you or someone else.

**My issue:** When I enter the disk decryption password on the splash screen it says it's wrong (I know it's the correct password since I frequently use the computer and have to enter this password).

@DanielT's solution in the comments of editing boot options worked for me.

**The (temporary) fix:**

1. During boot hold <kbd>shift</kbd> to show GRUB.
2. Select the first entry `Ubuntu` which leads to boot options
3. Remove `quiet splash` according to @DanielT's comment
4. Hit F10 to continue boot

Now there are some logs passing by until we're asked for the password. In my case, entering the password here successfully decrypted the disk.

---

**Update:** I used `$ sudo apt autoremove` to remove older kernels and now I can boot again without going through these steps. I'm wondering whether I was running out of space in the `/boot` partition and it was causing this problem but I didn't check how much space I had left beforehand.

Comment: My comment was supposed to be a req for info. If it works, then probably the plymounth kbd layout is wrong. Do `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` from https://askubuntu.com/q/434849/1004020 and `update-initramfs` solve it permanently?

Comment: @DanielT I don't think my issue was about the keyboard. I had to go through the steps above every time I rebooted the computer, but after I did `autoremove` to get rid of older kernels the problem disappeared. I rebooted right afterwards and it worked fine. I suspect my `\boot` partition was full but I didn't check it before the `autoremove` so I can't be sure. I didn't change anything else between the reboots that didn't work (had to use steps above) and the one that did work (after `autoremove`). I've updated the question with this info.

Comment: I'm glad the `autoremove` worked for you. I don't think `/boot` being full causes any problems because I mount mine read-only. I think the reason it worked is because somehow your initramfs and the scripts that generated them went out of sync somehow. When `apt autoremove` removes the kernel, it runs `update-grub` and maybe `update-initramfs`, which brings things back into sync